# Cannot set two div text in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm obviously new to jquery so I would appreciate some help on what should be something simple.  I have the following web page

```
<html><body>
<div id="mytitle1">Hello</div>
<p/>
<div id="mytitle2">World</div>
</body></html>
```

This renders fine.  But if I try to set the values in jquery as follows, only the first div is rendered.  When I debug I see that both divs are set but the second gets 'erased' from the rendered html page.  (inspecting the page after rendering I see only the first div).

```
<body>
<div id="title1" />
<p />
<div id="title2" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(showtitle);

    function showtitle() {
        $("#title1").text("Hello");
        $("#title2").text("World"); };
```

What gives?

Comment: ... and you've successfully received an error in your console re `showtitle`. Please check.

Comment: You surely have a js error, so it is not working.

Comment: Did you accidentally nest these two div's or is the code *exactly* like the last code block you posted above?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for calling the function is incorrect. You're currently putting the function reference inside a jQuery object, instead you want to just call it by placing `()` after its name.

You also need to wrap the code in a document.ready event handler to ensure that it only runs when the `#titleX` elements are available in the DOM. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  showtitle()

  function showtitle() {
    $("#title1").text("Hello");
    $("#title2").text("World");
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title1"></div>
<p></p>
<div id="title2"></div>
```

Also note that `<div>` and `<p>` elements are not self-closing, you need to add a separate `</div>` and `</p>` to close them as per the example above.

Comment: Thanks.  This works. I thought that $(functionname) was called when the document was ready but I see that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error with your HTML. You didn't close the divs. you must use closing tags on both divs. e.g: `</div>`. 
 Also, there is no such things as just `</p>`. The `<p>` tag is used for wrtinig paragraphs and should have an opening an closing tags.

Here try this code (it works for me):

```
<div id="title1"></div>
<div id="title2" ></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(showtitle);

    function showtitle() {
        $("#title1").text("Hello");
        $("#title2").text("World"); 
    };
</script>
```

Comment: You are correct.  the code was ok but the html was a problem.